# Can't access Oracle SQL Table

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I am using an Oracle Database and am trying to add a table, but unfortunately I don't have full access to the database, I created my table creation script and ran it locally without any issue ( I can select, insert, delete etc), After passing the same script to get run on the remote server I got the log back saying there were no errors. However I can not access my new table.

I can see the table using

```
SELECT *
FROM all_tables 
WHERE table_name = '[my New Table]'
```

However when I run

```
SELECT * 
FROM [my New Table]
```

I get an error: [Oracle]ORA-00942: table or view does not exist. I assume it is an issue with the permissions but can't find any  errors with my code

```
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT ON "[USER WHO CREATES THE TABLE]"."[my New Table]" to [MY_ROLE];
```

Below is the SQL execution code:

```
PROMPT Connecting as the application schema owner [owner] to &&dbname
ACCEPT ownerpassword char format [format] prompt "Please enter [owner] password: " hide
CONNECT [owner]/&ownerpassword@&&dbname

@@pr_dr_all.sql --(drops table if exists)
@@pr_cr_tables_tso_tcom.sql --(creates the table)
@@pr_gr_tso_tcom.sql --(sets grants)
@@pr_cr_constraints_tso_tcom.sql --(sets constraints)

PROMPT Connecting as the application user [user] to &&dbname
ACCEPT userpassword char format [format] prompt "Please enter [user] password: " hide 
CONNECT [user]/&userpassword@&&dbname

@@pr_dr_syn.sql --(drops synonyms)
@@pr_cr_syn_tso_tcom.sql --(creates synonyms)

spool off
```

pr_cr_tables_tso_tcom.sq:

```
CREATE TABLE "[owner]"."[table name]"
  (
    "[column 1]" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "[column 2]" NUMBER,
    "[column 3]" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
    "[column 4]" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
    "[column 5]" NUMBER,
    "[column 6]" NUMBER
  )
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE
  (
    INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
  )
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;

  CREATE SEQUENCE  [owner]."[table name]_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 99999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 81 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;

    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "[owner]"."[table name]_TRG" BEFORE
      INSERT ON [table name] FOR EACH ROW WHEN (NEW.ID IS NULL) BEGIN
      SELECT [table name]_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.ID FROM DUAL;
    END;
    /
    ALTER TRIGGER "[owner]"."[table name]_TRG" ENABLE;
```

pr_gr_tso_tcom.sql

```
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT ON "[owner]"."[table name]" to [role];
GRANT SELECT ON "[owner]"."[table name]_SEQ"  to [role];
```

pr_cr_syn_tso_tcom.sql

```
CREATE SYNONYM [table name]_SYN FOR "[owner]"."[table name]";
CREATE SYNONYM [table name]_SEQ_SYN FOR "[owner]"."[table name]_SEQ";
```

Comment: what error exactly you are getting??

Comment: Ask your DBA to grant you the create table privilege.

Comment: @Rony - updated with Error '[Oracle]ORA-00942: table or view does not exist'

Comment: @Rachcha - unfortunately that is not an option.

Comment: Have you confirmed the session context when you are querying from your new table (and qualifying the owner) and making sure the database user you are using has been granted the role which has been granted the select table privilege?

Comment: `SELECT * from all_tables WHERE table_name = '[my New Table]'`- check column `onwner` if the table is in your schema. Check your permissions on that table with `select * from TABLE_PRIVILEGES where TABLE_NAME = '[my New Table]'`

Comment: Do you run your select inside a PL/SQL Block (or Function/Procedure)? If yes, then privileges have to be granted to you directly - not through a role.

Comment: `[my New Table]` is an invalid name for a table or a column because a `[` is invalid in an SQL identifier. That's why you also need to those ugly double quotes. The rules for an identifier are documented in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to run the query from a different schema to the one that the table is located on you will need to prefix the table name with the schema, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM [schema that table is located on].[my New Table]
```

Otherwise you could create a synonym for the table name.

Comment: Thanks, this is working! I thought i had already tried this. Usually I do not need to do this, does that mean there is an issue with my synonyms?

Comment: I obviously can't see state of your synonyms, but you can check them out using the following: `select * from all_synonyms`

Comment: Thanks, my synonyms were the issue

Answer (score 2):

in any case you have to set schema for creating table , insert .... 
if not oracle will choose the default schema.

first make sure your tables created in right schema, contact them and ask for schema.if you didn't set schema so it is possible they created in other schema,

if you just pass them a sql file and they run it with sqlplus or other tools, it's so much more possible to make error.

start your sql file with following lines :

```
alter session set current_schema=PUTSchemaNameHere;

spool /folder/NameOfLog.log
set termout off
set echo on 
set feedback on 
set timing on 
set define off
```

the above code will generate a log in specified folder with desired name, so in case of any error you can trace back the error. (Or make sure table created)

if you pass them command one by one make sure to put the schema before the table name, procedure name, ....

for example the following command will create a table in desired schema

```
create table PutSchemaNameHere.TableName (column1 number,column2 varchar2(50));
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. I have updated my question with the code that is used, as far as I can tell the schema is set and is used in the table creation.